# Why is this condition always true?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic

Language: C
PIC: 16F84A
**Programm:CCS PCW**

When I compile the following code, my compiler complains that the FOR is always true(Maybe the int i doesnt support negative values?):

```
#include <16F84A.h>
#FUSES XT
#use delay(clock=4M)
byte const display[10] = {63,6,91,79,102,109,124,7,127,103};

void main()
{
   set_tris_b(0);
   while(True)
   {
   int i;
      for(i=9;i>=0;--i)
      {
         output_b(display[i]);
         delay_ms(300);
      }
   }
}
```

Its PIC Countdown project, so:
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8,7,6,...
but its stops after the first cycle.

Comment: If the language is C, why are there 5 language tags?

Comment: Why was this tagged `java` or `php`. I am not sure of `c#` either.

Comment: If this is the Microchip PIC compiler: it's crap. Their entire IDE is 120% broken, don't believe any of the "static analysis" results.

Comment: Your `While` condition is always true. The `for loop` is running with never ending. There is no way to get out from the loop.

Comment: Everything is alright with the "for" loop. The problem is in while loop

Comment: @NewDeveloper maybe you mean that the `for-loop` ends and then it starts again since its inside a `while(true)`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza-Yes. that is what I meant.

Comment: The only way for the `for` to have a problem would be if `i` was an `unsigned int`, but it is not the case (C99 standard states that plain `int` is a "signed integer type"), so either the compiler is broken or this is not exactly the code that generates the error.

Comment: dude, this solved.
I just change:
"int i" for "signed int i"

Comment: @Doc Kodam, this looks like problem of your IDE/Compiler....bcoz in C, int i is signed int i......for unsigned int i only you have to mention specifically

Comment: You are right @KinjalPatel

Comment: Can all PC programmers please refrain from answering embedded questions? _Every single embedded MCU program has an eternal loop in main_. Any embedded programming beginner knows this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
    signed int i;
```

instead of

```
    int i;
```

integers are unsigned by default in CCS compilers.

http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf

Check page 38

> "All types, except float, by default are unsigned; however, [they] may be preceded by unsigned or signed.

Comment: -1 No, this answer is blatantly wrong, `int` is _signed_ by default.

Comment: @Lundin , thanks for voting down without double checking!
http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf
Check page 38
"All types, except float, by default are unsigned; however, [they] 
may be preceded by unsigned or signed. "

Comment: If your answer only applies on some non-standard junk compiler, you should make that obvious. Otherwise we will have to assume that your answer is about the C programming language, for which your answer is incorrect. See the standard C11 6.2.5.

Comment: @Lundin the compiler was specified in the question, I'll edit the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is either broken or it is some non-standard crap where `int` is unsigned by default.

I would advice to use a real, conforming C compiler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the assembly code generated by the compiler, and you will know for sure. Or post it here, so that we do not have to own / install the specific compiler. Good think with assembly (specially on dead simple micros like PIC16) is that it can never hide what it actually does :-)

I agree with some comments here about the quality of some tools, and Microchip has never had their own PIC16 C compiler anyway so that we cannot blame them :-(

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that it is related to the `for` condition and
variable type on decremental `for`:

- use variable type as signed `int8` or `signed int16`,
- stop condition set it as `i>-1;`

this removes the warning and the code runs fine:

```
#include <16f84a.h>
#fuses XT, NOWDT
#use delay(clock=4000000)

void main(){
    set_tris_b(0x00);
    output_b(0x00);
    signed int16 i, unid, dec, dato;
    while(true){
        for(i=99; i>-1; i--){
            dec = i/10;
            unid = i - (dec*10);
            dato = (dec<<4) + unid;
            output_b((int8)dato);
            delay_ms(50);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you realize you're posting an answer to a question asked 10 years ago?  Are you trying to help that person, or are you having a similar problem?